# (Battery not working) How to know if the issue is in the laptop or the battery?

Tags: windows-10, battery

I recently bought a new battery for an hp pavilion 17 running windows 10. The laptop wouldn't turn on with the battery plugged in, so i assumed it was wasn't charged. When i turned the laptop on with the AC adapter, it showed the charge percentage at 72%, and that the battery was charging, once it reached 100%, it showed the message `Plugged in, not charging`. However when i tried to run my laptop using the battery alone, it still wouldn't turn on. I assumed the problem was with the battery, so i ran a few tests, the battery report generated from `powercfg /batteryreport` showed both total capacity and current capacity to be equal, around 35000mWh. I installed `BatteryCare`, and it showed the same result with wear level being 0.00%. I wasn't sure what to do, so i plugged my old battery and to my surprise it showed the same results as the above, meaning it wasn't damaged at all, and there was no need for a replacement. So my question is, is there still any chance that the battery is damaged, or is my laptop at fault, in which case how can i find out what's wrong ?

Comment: With the _old_ battery plugged in and charged, can you run the computer without being plugged in to AC? If so, I would suspect something wrong with the new battery; if not, I would bet on a problem with the computer.

Comment: Also the new battery can be perfectly fine but not correctly recognized by the firmware (BIOS or UEFI). Some manufacturers use several "tricks" to prevent the use of non-genuine parts.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin the old battery is at 0%, and it's showing "Plugged -in, not charging". I've tried to get to work for a while but couldn't, that's why i bough a new one.

Comment: @MichaelBay how can i render it recognizable by the firmware ?, if at all possible

Comment: If genuine it should just work; if not it may not be possible. Sometimes a BIOS/UEFI update makes it works, other times it's the opposite. And another possibility is the new battery not being compatible for some reason. It may fit but not work. Some years ago a co-worker found out that for a certain Compal line of laptops, batteries looking exactly the same were not interchangeable between models.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Disconnect AC

Shutdown

Remove main battery (if possible)

Connect AC

Startup

Open Device Manager

Click the plus (+) sign next to Batteries category, right-click all of the "Microsoft ACPI Compliant Control Method Battery" listings, and select Uninstall In the "Confirm Device Uninstall" dialog box, click OK. (it’s ok if you only have 1 of these).

Click the plus (+) sign next to System Devices.
Right-click the “ACPI Fixed Features Button" and select Uninstall. In the "Confirm Device Uninstall" dialog box, click OK.

Shutdown

Disconnect AC

Insert battery

Connect AC

Startup

Comment: I'm afraid it didn't work, nor did a few variations of this trick. I'm just going to conclude that it's a hardware issue.